# Math exchange rates

Tags: math, currency

Currently I've got a database of exchange rates from USD > Currency

```
+----------+---------+
| Currency | USDRate |
+----------+---------+
| USD      | 1.00    |
| GBP      | 0.7418  |
| SEK      | 8.29    |
+----------+---------+
```

Simple math which I've been doing is converting the **USD** to another currency on my site with this:

```
price * rate
```

But what if I want to do **GBP** to **USD**, I've tried the following:

```
price * (rate - 1 * rate)
```

Should be such simple math but it's completely threw me.

Comment: **GBP** to **USD** will be *x/GBP_rate*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it **is** a matter of simple mathematics, not of programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes you have a table, with a column of prices in one currency, say GBP, which you want to convert to SEK, e.g.

```
prices
1.35
1.07
4.53
...
```

If you wanted to convert your GBP prices to SEK, you would use the following formula:

```
price * (1 / rate_GBP) * (rate_SEK) = price in SEK
```

To make use of your forex table, you may join the price table twice to it.  This can be achieved through the following query:

```
SELECT
    p.prices AS orig_price_gbp,
    p.prices * (1 / r1.USDRate) * (r2.USDRate)
FROM table_prices p
INNER JOIN rates r1
    ON r1.Currency = 'GBP'
INNER JOIN rates r2
    ON r2.Currency = 'SEK';
```

Not much magic here; the basic idea is to bring the source and destination currency rates together for each price, then apply the formula to do the forex.